# Multiple Consumer Threads Consume Queue FIFO Overall

Tags: java, multithreading, fifo

As I am trying to learn the multi-threading part of JAVA programming, I have the following issue when dealing with One Producer - Multiple Consumer coding.

What I'm trying to achieve is: multiple consumer threads taking items out of the queue in the order of how they were put into the queue. in other words, make the consumer threads maintain a FIFO manner overall.

```
final BlockingDeque<String> deque = new LinkedBlockingDeque<String>();

Runnable rb = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println(deque.takeLast());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

deque.putFirst("a");
deque.putFirst("b");
deque.putFirst("c");
deque.putFirst("d");

ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
pool.submit(rb);
pool.submit(rb);
pool.submit(rb);
pool.submit(rb);
```

WHAT I AM LOOKING FOR:
a
b
c
d

WHAT IT ACTUALLY OUTPUTS:
b
c
a
d

OR in random orders

Any simple solutions to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: you need to synchronize output
`synchronized (deque) {
                try {
                    System.out.println(deque.takeLast());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the problem is that

```
System.out.println(deque.takeLast());
```

are actually two instructions which together are not atomic. Imagine such scenario :

1. Thread 1 takes string from queue.
2. Thread 2 takes string from queue.
3. Thread 2 prints value.
4. Thread 1 prints value.

So it all depends how operating system will manage the threads execution.

In your case one possible solution would be to add `synchronized` keyword to `run` method :

```
Runnable rb = new Runnable() {
    public synchronized void run() {
         try {
              String s = deque.takeLast();
              System.out.println(s);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
};
```

This will synchronize on instance of anonymous class which you created here. Since you are passing the same runnable to ExecutorService - it should work.
Or you can synchornize on your `queue` object since your runnable, which has access to queue object, will be executed in many threads, as you passed it to `ExecutorService` :

```
Runnable rb = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        synchronized (deque) {
             try {
                 String s = deque.takeLast();
                 System.out.println(s);
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
        }
    }
};
```

Also remember about closing your thread pool because now your application will never exit.